# MSVC 2008 error 'Type' is not a struct (although it is)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, language-lawyer, friend

The following MWE compiles on gcc 4.8.2 but not on MSVC 2008 (company policy)

```
struct B
{
};

struct A
{
    typedef B Handler;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef typename T::Handler  Type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    friend struct Foo<T>::Type;     // MSVC 2008 does not like this
    typedef typename Foo<T>::Type   Foo;
};

int main() 
{
}
```

MSVC 2008 error

```
error C2649: 'Foo<T>::Type' : is not a 'struct'
```

Is this a compiler bug or am I doing something illegal here? More importantly is there a fix?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6626831/1870232

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `struct` keyword and replace it with `typename`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    friend typename Foo<T>::Type;     
    typedef typename Foo<T>::Type   Foo;
};
```

Comment: (Un)fortunately it [_`compiles`_](http://rextester.com/TIB93137) without `typename` too on VC++, may be compiler bug ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be invalid. [class.friend]/3:

> A `friend` declaration that does not declare a function shall have one
>   of the following forms:
>  `friend`
>   *elaborated-type-specifier*`;`
>  `friend` *simple-type-specifier*`;`
>  `friend` *typename-specifier*`;`

However, there is an important restriction on elaborated-type-specifiers: [dcl.type.elab]/2:

> **If the identifier resolves to a typedef-name** […] the
>   elaborated-type-specifier is ill-formed.

In that respect, GCC and Clang are wrong and, surprisingly, VC++ is right.
You can make use of the third bullet of the first quote and use a typename-specifier.

```
friend typename Foo<T>::Type;
```